# Error Installing "psycopg2" python module for creating connection to PostgreSQL via Python 2.7 on macOS

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, psycopg2

also tried installing psycopg2-binary as well but same error (not sure what am I missing here, new to PostgreSQL and PyCharm)

```
pip install psycopg2
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

**Error message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2365, in resolve
    raise ImportError(str(exc))
ImportError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. first of all run `easy_install --upgrade pip` command to upgrade your pip.
2. then type and run this

```
from pip._internal import main
main(['install', 'psycopg2'])
```

3. After that run this

```
main(['install', 'psycopg2-binary'])
```